GFCI receptacle serving refrigerator tripped 4 days after switching off door heater
This summer I installed a GFCI receptacle to serve only the refrigerator. It would randomly trip. So I called Samsung Technical Support for asssistance. They suggested resetting the refrigerator control board. The refrigerator draws 3.0 amps maximum. It is equipped with a door heater which you can turn off if not needed for exterior door condensation. A search found that heaters can be a source of soft grounds due to moisture in the insulation. Therefore I switched off the door heater.
After switching off the refrigerator door heater, it appeared that  random trips of the GFCI receptacle on my refrigerator 15 Amp circuit was a non issue….however after 4 days it tripped again. I wonder what the cause could be now? There were two trips within 15 minutes around suppertime 5 pm. This is a peak time for electrical use. Could there have been a power sag that could cause the GFCI receptacle sense a slight difference in the amps on the hot wire and the neutral wire?
If we have a power outage, all other kitchen counter GCFI receptacles come back on with the power restoration, but not the refrigerator GFCI receptacle…..it needs to be reset….why?

Refrigerators are supposed to be on dedicated circuits and then not using GFCI protection since it is not needed.
If your fridge is on a dedicated circuit, use a regular outlet or better a single outlet.  Then you don't have the GFCI issues you have.
If you don't have the fridge on a dedicated circuit, you should have one installed.
The issues you are experiancing is one of the reasons dedicated circuits to outlets behind the refrigerator are the most common method of powering a refrigerator.  If your outlet is not behind the fridge, consider adding one.  If it is, you don't need a GFCI, unless you have weird people that want to move the fridge and play with the outlet.

Thank you for your response. My refrigerator is on a dedicated 15Amp circuit. I installed the GFCI receptacle for safety because it is within easy reach to the kitchen sink.

If The outlet is not behind the refrigerator, consider extending the circuit, putting an outlet behind the fridge and removing the existing outlet and  covering with a blank cover.

@RoyHill   A GFCI receptacle is required if within 6 feet of the sink, about the distance of both hands touching the receptacle/fridge and the sink

Thank you for your advice. I will remove the GFCI receptacle and replace with a  single outlet supplying the refrigerator. The receptacle will be relocated to behind the refrigerator.


Today at the recommendation from Electrician on Home Improvement DIY forum:

Remove GFCI receptacle from refrigerator because of nuisance trips caused by Defrost Cycle Heaters, and door Heaters.
Ensure Refrigerator is on its own separate 15 Amp circuit which is not shared by any other electrical load.
Move countertop receptacle behind refrigerator to ensure that no person can have their hand in the kitchen sink basin water and also touching the refrigerator powered receptacle at the same time to prevent electrocution!

Therefore I did the following electrical modifications for the refrigerator receptacle:

Removed GFCI receptacle and replaced with single standard receptacle. Ensuring that it cannot be used by any other electrical load except the refrigerator.✅
Retained countertop receptacle location fed by separate 15 Amp circuit from main panel circuit breaker.✅
Install weatherproof cover over new single receptacle counter top for the refrigerator. This ensures that no person can touch the refrigerator receptacle at the same time as immersed hand in kitchen sink water.✅

All electrical conditions satisfied✅

The refrigerator have a automatic defrost feature. It is time controlled.
It turns off the compressor and turns on the heaters to defrost.
Since your GFCI triggers at specific time it could be the automatic defrost cycle.
Inspect the heaters.

Thank you for this information. The defrost heater is most likely the culprit causing GFCI receptacle to trip. I have decided to remove the GFCI and replace with single outlet and relocated behind the refrigerator.

@RoyHill you are welcome

Some follow up:

I did the following electrical modifications for the refrigerator receptacle:
1.) Removed GFCI receptacle and replaced with single standard receptacle. Ensuring that it cannot be used by any other electrical load except the refrigerator.✅
2.) Retained countertop receptacle location fed by separate 15 Amp circuit from main panel circuit breaker.✅
3.) Install weatherproof cover over new single receptacle counter top for the refrigerator. This ensures that no person can touch the refrigerator receptacle at the same time as immersed hand in kitchen sink basin water.

@RoyHill nice work
